# If $E\subset Y\subset X$ and $X$ is a metric space then give the example & prove the Theorem stated below.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $E\subset Y\subset X$, where $X$ is a metric space.

1. Give an example such that $E$ is closed relative to $Y$, but not closed relative to $X$.
2. Show that $E$ is closed relative to $Y$ iff $E=Y\cap F$ for some closed set $F$ of $X$.

This question came to me when I was reading Sec. 2.32 (Compact Sets) from **Baby Rudin**. The questions are not explicitly stated in the book. So if any of them is false, then sorry and provide proof. But I suspect both the questions are true.

Comment: You write that you "suspect both questions are true". Can you explain the nature of your suspicions? Or anything that you might have tried when you investigated these questions?

Comment: I believe the second one is false just by definition. For the first one, did you try to come up with any examples?

Comment: Sorry the second question was false, so I have made correction.

Comment: What are the open sets of $(Y,d|_{Y \times Y})$, to you? It'll help in the proof of 2., after that the example can be found.

Comment: For the first question it is trivial to construct an example with $E=Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open balls in $(X,d)$ are of the form $B_X(a,r):=\{x \in X: d(a,x)<r\}$, then the open balls in $(Y,d)$ (let's write $d|_{Y\times Y}=d$) should be $B_Y(a,r):=\{x \in Y: d(a,x)<r\}$ but then $B_Y(a,r)=B_X(a,r)\cap Y$ and this is true for any open ball. **The same is true for any open set too**. Let $O\subseteq Y$ be open relative to $Y$, since $O$ is an open neighborhood of each of its points (relative to Y), for each $x_\alpha \in O,~~~\exists~~~r_\alpha>0$ such that $x_\alpha \in B_X(x_\alpha,r_\alpha)\cap Y\subseteq O$. So $\cup_\alpha (B_X(x_\alpha,r_\alpha)\cap Y)=O$ (you can show if $x_\alpha \in O$ then $x_\alpha \in B_X(x_\alpha,r_\alpha)\cap Y$) this implies $(\cup_{\alpha}B_X(x_\alpha,r_\alpha))\cap Y=O$. $B_X(x_\alpha,r_\alpha)$'s are open in $X$ and arbitrary union of open sets are open so our claim is proved.\

Now we prove 2. $\Rightarrow$   Let $E$ is closed relative to $Y$ then $Y\setminus E$ is open relative to $Y$, there exists an open set $O$ in $X$ such that $Y\setminus E = Y \cap O$ from which you can show  that $E=Y \cap (X \setminus O)$ where $X \setminus O=F$.\

$\Rightarrow$   Let $F$ be closed in $X$ and $E=Y \cap F$. We will show any $y \in Y \setminus E$ is not a limit point of $E$ relative $Y$. Note that $y \notin F$, there exists an open ball $B_X(y,r)$ in $X$ such that $B_X(y,r) \cap F=\phi $ which implies $(Y \cap B_X(y,r))\cap (Y \cap F)=\phi$. Thus $E$ is closed in $Y$.\

1. Take $X=\mathbb{R},~Y=(0,1),~E=[\frac{1}{2},1)$ then $E=Y \cap [\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

**2.30 Theorem:**  Suppose $E\subset Y\subset X$. $E$ is open relative to $Y$ iff $E=Y\cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.

**Proof of 2:**
Suppose $E$ is closed relative to $Y$. Then $Y\setminus E$ is open relative to $Y$ and $Y\setminus E=Y\cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$. $p\in E\Rightarrow p\notin Y\setminus E\Rightarrow p\in Y$ but $p\notin G\Rightarrow p\in Y$ and $p\in X\setminus G$. So $E\subset Y\cap X\setminus G$. Again $q\in Y\cap X\setminus G\Rightarrow q\in Y$  but $q\notin G\Rightarrow q\in Y $ but $q\notin Y\cap G=Y\setminus E\Rightarrow q\in E$. Thus $Y\cap F=E$, where $F=X\setminus G$ is a closed subset of X.

*Conversely*, let $F$ is closed in $X$ and $E=Y\cap F$. Now $t\in Y\setminus E\Rightarrow t\notin F\Rightarrow V_t\cap F=\emptyset$ for some open ball $V_t$ in $X\Rightarrow (Y\cap V_t)\cap (Y\cap F)=\emptyset\Rightarrow (V_t\cap Y)\cap E=\emptyset$.
So $t$ is not a limit point of $E$ relative to $Y$ and $E$ is closed relative to $Y$.